# Most pythonic way to construct an object not in a container?

Tags: python, containers

Consider a list, or more generally a container `C`, that contains different hashable objects of different types.

I would like to construct an hashable object that is not in `C` in a efficient and pythonic way.

Currently, I do the following:

```
i = 0

while i in C:           # while i is in the container C
    i += 1

# at the end of the loop, i is not in C
```

However, it feels very inefficient and not very pythonic...

So my question is: given a container that contains different hashable objects, what is the best way to construct an hashable object that is not in this container?

(For context, I am doing some graph theory and I need to add to my graph a temporary and artificial node that I shall remove later.)

Comment: You want to add something in the container, so `G.add_node(i)` seems unavoidable and pretty much Pythonic. For your particualr use case though I think `i = len(G.nodes())` shall do the same without a loop

Comment: @Alexey Larionov I do not understand your answer. `len(G.nodes())` can already be a node of G (for instance if the nodes of G are `3,'A', 'B'`. Otherwise yeah of course I cannot avoid  `G.add_node(i)`, I was talking about avoiding this loop.

Comment: This might be an interesting question, but I suggested you to rewrite the question, as the example that you brought seems almost irrelevant. Also, I would avoid using the term graph at all in the question, I would only focus on a list of objects of possibly different types

Comment: @Héhéhé If I were to do this, I would cut corners and make some rule that you can't insert nodes that are strings starting `$$$`. So that I could safely memorize some counter of artificial nodes e.g. 2, meaining that nodes `['$$$0', '$$$1']`, are already in the graph and the next artificial node I would insert is `$$$2`, and increase the counter

Comment: You can also come up with generating a random string of say 30 characters, making it probabalistically unreal to collide with some existing node

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be simplified by using [`Graph.__len__`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.__len__.html#graph-len):

```
G.add_node(len(G))
```

Note however that this approach works only if you know a priori that your graph only contains nodes `0 .. len(G) - 1`.

To solve the general problem of finding an object that is not in the container, I would create a new class from scratch. Here is an example:

```
container = ['A', 3, None, 3.0, True]
class MyClass:
    _hash_val = max([hash(x) for x in container]) + 1
    def __hash__(self):
        return MyClass._hash_val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, MyClass)
container.append(MyClass())
```

Comment: This does not work in general, `len(G.nodes())` can already be a node of `G` (for instance if the nodes of G are `3`, `'A'` and `'B'`.

Comment: Sure, that's why I added a note. Let me try to find a more general solution.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your note before I post my answer :/